# wordpress api and flutter app, problem in a variable

Tags: wordpress, flutter

I am trying to do a test exercise of the wordpress api in flutter. But I get this silly error and I don't know how to fix it to be able to debug

if you can help me please:

[image]

Comment: Please post code as actual text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example# for details on how to do this.  That way people can actually try to reproduce your issue and test their proposed answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing the problem because of the 'Dart Null-Safety' support. If you are working with a nullable value, you should check for null or '!' You can force it to work with expression.

Please change code like below lines;

from

```dart
snapshot.data.length
```

to

```dart
snapshot.data!.length
```

Comment: I have tried it, it is the solution that the visual studio corrector puts, but the error continues to appear. As snapshot.data [index] also gives error

Comment: If you don't post the details of the error, I can't tell you the solution to the error. Could you please post the updated status of the error?